# Need fixing generic posting on facebook

Tags: posts, facebook

The problem becomes apparent when we ''post'' something on facebook. For example right now if I write: '' I love this website, check it out at www.5starpma.com'' we get the image of a male model. What we want to see is the image of the logo or at least, the image of the HOME page of the website.

Like this example: ''Love www.apple.com''
we get the Apple logo.

[image]

Comment: These are done via opengraph tags

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to do if you have access to edit the header of your website. All you need to do is enter the appropriate [Open Graph metadata](http://ogp.me/) for each page.

ie (and taken steaight from http://ogp.me/):

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

If you have entered the appropriate data, and you're not seeing the changes right away - try [de-linting the URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

**Edit:** There are many good wordpress plugins that can handle this too. [Yoast](https://yoast.com/) is my personal favourite, but there are more out there.